# Converting string to date. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have table with column COL1(char 23) with full date e.g. '2007-11-13 12:34:49:012'. Now I want to change my date to '2007-11-12 59:59:59:999' (last moment in day before). 
Why the convert paremeters dont work property? My query:

```
convert(varchar(10),convert(date,DateAdd(day,-1,COL1),121)) + ' 23:59:59:999'
```

After

```
DateAdd(day,-1,COL1)
```

i get: "Nov 12 2007" and this is my problem.
Finally i get: "Nov 12 200 23:59:59:999"

Comment: Why don't you Google first?!

Comment: Every person you seek advice from will tell you the same thing: do not store dates as varchars

Comment: It's special case and i must do it in this way

Comment: can you tell me the result of `select @@LANGUAGE` Im having trouble reproducing the problem

Comment: The output format of a date should be done in the UI code not the database.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select dateadd(millisecond, -1, dateadd(day, 1, cast(left(col1, 10) as datetime)))
```

Comment: Now i cant test it. But i think your query return type as DateTime and i prefere varchar

Comment: @iTuj . . . There is no accounting for taste.  You should store and use date/time values in the native formats in the database.  However, you can use `convert()` to convert the value to a string, if you really desire that.

Answer (score 0):

Varchar(10) isn't quite ling enough for the data try varchar(11)

Comment: I know but i want convert 'Nov 12 2007' to '2007-11-12'

Comment: @iTuj - sorry missed that... can you tell me the result of `
select @@LANGUAGE` Im having trouble reproducing the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select cast(dateadd(ms, -1, cast(convert(varchar(8), cast(col1 as datetime), 112) as datetime2)) as varchar(23))
```